# create spring boot 2.7 'mvn spring-boot:build-image' failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Building docker image using spring-boot-maven-plugin failing.

```
[INFO] Retrying request to {}->docker://localhost:2376
[INFO] I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->docker://localhost:2376: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory
[INFO] Retrying request to {}->docker://localhost:2376
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' 100%
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.805 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-19T00:13:53+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.5:build-image (default-cli) on project demodocker: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.5:build-image failed: Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "[2] No such file or directory"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

[image: screenshot]

build a docker image with spring-boot-maven-plugin not working.